# How do I preserve existing subtitles in a clip when using KDENLive?

Tags: video, kdenlive

I'm editing my drone videos with KDENLive 22.04.2 on Ubuntu 20.04.

I discovered by accident that my drone actually records telemetry data in the subtitles track of the videos that it produces.  It's really neat to be able to see exactly how high and how fast I was going while I'm viewing the videos. All I have to do is turn on subtitles.

Here's the problem: when I edit a video with KDENLive and render it, the subtitles all get stripped out of the result. It doesn't even show that they're in the original clip, but I can see them when I play the clip in a different program like VLC.  I can find lots of information on how to ***add*** subtitles in KDENLive, either manually or via speech-to-text.  But I can't figure out how to keep the existing subtitles that DJI puts in there. The telemetery data are nowhere to be found.

Is there any way to maintain the original subtitles across the editing process?

Comment: My terminology may be incorrect; when I say "subtitles" I really mean "closed captioning".  I'm assuming that they are the same thing?